# Generate all valid combinations of N pairs of parentheses

Tags: algorithm, recursion, combinations, parentheses

UPDATE (task detailed Explanation):
We have a string consist of numbers 0 and 1, divided by operators |, ^ or &. The task is to create all fully parenthesized expressions. So the final expressions should be divided into "2 parts"

For example

```
0^1 -> (0)^(1) but not extraneously: 0^1 -> (((0))^(1))
```

Example for expression 1|0&1:

```
(1)|((0)&(1))
((1)|(0))&(1)
```

As you can see both expressions above have left and write part:

```
left: (1); right: ((0)&(1))
left: ((1)|(0)); right: (1)
```

I tried the following code, but it does not work correctly (see output):

```
// expression has type string
// result has type Array (ArrayList in Java)
function setParens(expression, result) {
  if (expression.length === 1) return "(" + expression + ")";


  for (var i = 0; i < expression.length; i++) {
    var c = expression[i];
    if (c === "|" || c === "^" || c === "&") {
        var left  = expression.substring(0, i);
        var right = expression.substring(i + 1);

         leftParen = setParens(left, result);
         rightParen = setParens(right, result);
         var newExp = leftParen + c + rightParen;
         result.push(newExp);
    }
  }
  return expression;    
}

function test() {
  var r = [];
  setParens('1|0&1', r);
  console.log(r);
}

test();

code output: ["(0)&(1)", "(0)|0&1", "(1)|(0)", "1|0&(1)"]
```

Comment: looks a homework to me. what's the language your program's in?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr looks like Javascript

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr example is in JavaScript. Basically, language doesn't matter for me, you could write answer in any other language :)

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question. Where in the code you've written does it reference the number of parentheses pairs? Are you looking for all possible ways to parenthesize an expression, or are you looking for all valid combinations of N pairs of parentheses?

Comment: @JimMischel all possible ways to parenthesize an expression

Comment: Please change the title to match.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, this can get pretty involved. Are you worried about operator precedence? For example, 1+2*3 can be parenthesized as 1|(2&3) or (1|2)&3. Do you care that the results will be different? Do you need to support unary operators like `!`? What other operators do you need to support? In general, you need to write an expression parser; *ad-hoc* methods like the code you posted won't take all possibilities into account.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  "it does not work correctly" is not a problem specification.  You should also outline your algorithm; single-letter variables names and ambiguous interface (you alter `result` and return `expression`) don't help your case.

Comment: Also, you're not really looking for *all possible ways*. The number of ways to parenthesize any expression is infinite. Trivially, you can always add another level of parentheses. That is, `(2+2)` can be further parenthesized as `((2+2))`.

Comment: If you're having trouble with the algorithm itself, you should research other algorithms and implementations (this is a common problem in on-line postings).

Comment: @JimMischel Just update my question with detailed description  what I need from function.

Comment: @Prune I already have spent 8 days trying to figure out how to implement that. The problem is: I even don't understand from what point I should start think to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input expression is not already partially parenthesized and you want only fully parenthesized results:

```
FullyParenthesize(expression[1...n])

    result = {}

    // looking for operators
    for p = 1 to n do

        // binary operator; parenthesize LHS and RHS
        // parenthesize the binary operation
        if expression[p] is a binary operator then
            lps = FullyParenthesize(expression[1 ... p - 1])
            rps = FullyParenthesize(expression[p + 1 ... n])
            for each lp in lps do
                for each rp in rps do
                    result = result U {"(" + lp + expression[p] + rp + ")"}

    // no binary operations <=> single variable
    if result == {} then
        result = {"(" + expression + ")")}

    return result
```

Example: 1|2&3

```
FullyParenthesize("1|2&3")
    result = {}
    binary operator | at p = 2;
    lps = FullyParenthesize("1")
              no operators
              result = {"(" + "1" + ")"}
              return result = {"(1)"}
    rps = Parenthesize("2&3")
              result = {"2&3", "(2&3)"}
              binary operator & at p = 2
                  lps = Parenthesize("2")
                            no operators
                            result = {"(" + "2" + ")"}
                            return result = {"(2)"}
                  rps = Parenthesize("3")
                            no operators
                            result = {"(" + "3" + ")"}
                            return result = {"(3)"}
                  lp = "(2)"
                      rp = "(3)"
                          result = result U {"(" + "(2)" + "&" + "(3)" + ")"}
                  return result = {"((2)&(3))"}
    lp = "(1)"
        rp = "((2)&(3))"
            result = result U {"(" + "(1)" + "|" + "((2)&(3))" + ")"}

    binary operator & at p = 4
    ...
            result = result U {"(" + "((1)|(2))" + "&" + "(3)" + ")"}

    return result {"((1)|((2)&(3)))", "(((1)|(2))&(3))"}
```

You will have 2^k unique fully parenthesized expressions (without repeated parentheses) given an input expression with k binary operators.

Comment: Thank you for your pseudo code. One thing that I don't get: in line "else if expression[p] is a binary operator then" you use "else-if" statement. It seems that you miss somewhere first "if" statment

Comment: @NoNameQA Good catch. I originally wrote it with support for unary operators as well, but after your edits I saw you only use binary operators. I will remove the "else".